# Error after installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I try to install mod_wsgi on my windows 7 64x machine.

I installed the apache 2.2 win 32 and the Pyhton 2.7 win32 for all users.
At the apache config file i added the line
"LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"

I copy the file mod_wsgi-4.4.11+ap22vc9-cp27-none-win32.whl to modules and renamed it to mod_wsgi.so.

when i want to start the apache server i get the Syntaxerror for the line i added in the config file before. The apache doesn't start.

all in all i do these steps

> install apache2.2 win32
>
> install python 2.7 win32
>
> add line in apache config -> LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
>
> add mod_wsgi.so to apache/modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .whl file is a special zip file, not a .so file, you can't simply rename it like that. Either work out what wheels are and how to use them, or use the more official builds of mod_wsgi described at:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

and available from:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases